# split big array into multiple arrays where empty element occurs in php

Tags: php

```
This is Input:-print_r($result4);
Output:-Array ( [0] => A-I-only [1] => B-III-only [2] => C-I-and-II-only [3]=>  D-II-and-III-only [4] => E-I,-II,-III [5] => [6] => A-Hepatitis-A [7] => B-Hepatitis-B [8] => C-Hepatitis-C [9] => D-Hepatitis-B-and-C [10] => E-None-of-the-above [11] => [12] => A)-Cholestasis [13] => B)-Cholecystitis [14] => C)-Cholelithiasis [15] => D)-Hepatic-encephalopathy [16] => E)-Ascites [17] => [18] => A-Acetyl-salicylic-acid [19] => B-Ibuprofen [20] => C-Acetaminophen [21] => D-Pepto-Bismol [22] => E-All-of-the-above [23] => [24] => [25] => A-dark-urine [26] => B-stomach-pain [27] => C-blood-in-stools [28] => D-yellowing-of-skin [29] => E-Yellowing-of-eye-and-mucus [30] => [31] => A-Hepatitis-A [32] => B-Hepatitis-B [33] => C-Dukoral [34] => D-Gerdasil [35] => E-None-of-the-above [36] => [37] => cervical-cancer-caused-by-papilloma-virus [38] => A-Glucuronidation [39] => B-Glutathione-conjugation [40] => C-Acetylation [41] => D-Sulfate-conjugation [42] => E-Methylation [43] => [44] => A-Acetylcysteine [45] => B-cysteine [46] => C-Mercapturic-acid [47] => D-Glutathione-conjugation [48] => E-Glutathione-only [49] => [50] => administered-in-teenagers-to-prevent-cervical-cancer. [51] => A-Hepatitis-A [52] => B-Hepatitis-C [53] => C-Hepatitis-D [54] => D-Hepatitis-A,-B-&-C [55] => E-Hepatitis-A,-B-&-D [56] => [57] => [58] => A)-ALT [59] => B)-AST [60] => C)-Bilirubin- [61] => D)-Albumin [62] => E)-Proteins [63] => [64] => A--Saliva- [65] => B-Bile- [66] => C-Pancreatic-duct---- [67] => D-Gastric-secretions [68] => [69] => A)-Sexual-contact [70] => B)-Blood-transfusion [71] => C-Food-and-drink-contamination [72] => D-Traveling-abroad [73] => E-Drugs [74] => [75] => A)-Hepatitis-A-only [76] => B)-Hepatitis-B-only [77] => C)-Hepatitis-A-and-B [78] => D)-Hepatitis-A,-B-and-C [79] => E)-Hepatitis-B-and-C [80] => [81] => [82] => A)-Proton-pump-inhibitors [83] => B)-Warfarin [84] => C)-antacids [85] => D)Lipid-soluble-drugs [86] => E)-Parenteral-drugs [87] => [88] => A)-spironolactone- [89] => B)-NSAIDs- [90] => C)-acetaminophen- [91] => D)-Ibuprofen- [92] => E)-codeine [93] => [94] => A)-constipation- [95] => B)-ascites- [96] => C)-encephalitis- [97] => D)-liver-cirrhosis- [98] => E)-Hepatitis [99] => [100] => encephalitis. [101] => contaminated-hepatitis? [102] => A)-Hepatitis-A [103] => B)-Hepatitis-B [104] => C)-Hepatitis-A-and-B [105] => D)-Hepatitis-C [106] => E)-Hepatitis-D [107] => [108] => A)-Hepatitis-A [109] => [110] => B)-Hepatitis-A-and-B [111] => C)-Hepatitis-B-and-C [112] => D)-Hepatitis-A,-B,-C [113] => [114] => [115] => )
```

now i want to split array into multiple arrays where empty element occurs like

```
Array ( [0] => A-I-only [1] => B-III-only [2] => C-I-and-II-only [3]=>  D-II-and-III-only [4] => E-I,-II,-III ) Array([6] => A-Hepatitis-A [7] => B-Hepatitis-B [8] => C-Hepatitis-C [9] => D-Hepatitis-B-and-C [10] => E-None-of-the-above )....similarly
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below will work,

```
$new_array = array();
$i = 0;

foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
    if (!empty($v))
    {
        $new_array[$i][$k] = $v;
        continue;
    }
    $i++;
}

//This will fix your missing fourth index<br/>
$new_array = array_values($new_array);
var_dump($new_array);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yyV5gr)**.

Comment: Which one? Have you checked the demo?

Comment: rikesh she is talking about the missing index 4 which has occurred when two consecutive values are empty in the array

Comment: What is your expected output?